# Swift-UI display parent view name in the navigation link text when going to back parent view

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, navigation

I have ImageSettingView which Im using multiple places. When I used this view at multiple place in my project it takes static name all time in the navigationBarItem i.e Text("Image Collab View"). I want to give dynamic name change  based on where parent view it comes from.

ImageColorView -> ImageSettingView (Back NavButon text - ImageColor )
ProfilePictureView -> ImageSettingView (Back NavButon text - ProfilePictureView )

Sample code of ImageSettingView :-

```
 struct ImageSettingView : View {


 var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            VStack {
                Form {
                Text("Image View")
                }
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading:
                        Button(action: {
                            onUserImage()
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Image(systemName: "backward")
                                Text("Image Collab View")
                                // I want to use change above text based on what name of the parent view was
                            }
                        },
                    trailing:
                        Button(action: {
                            onDelete()
                        }) {
                            HStack {
                                Text("Delete")
                            }
                        }
                )
             
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could just pass the name of the parent view, and adding `@State var parentName: String`
 to your `ImageSettingView`, then use this in the `Text(parentName)`

Comment: I didn't you. You mean using state in one view and use binding in other place. Right ?